# Unit Testing Complex Query

Tags: mysql, unit-testing

Currently I need to test a complex query which join multiple tables with lots of filtering such as the object is deleted, suspended, private and the owner of the object is suspended or not etc.

Should I prepare fixtures for every combination of the scenarios and test the query output correct result for each fixtures.

Or should I break the testing into smaller parts which each part tests a specific filtering rules like an unit test for testing correct filtering base on object status and another unit test for testing correct filtering base on owner status. And combining the two unit tests the whole query is tested.

Any one have any suggestion? Or is there better way to refactor such query or methods to be more easy to test.

Comment: Sorry, what's the purpose of unit testing here?

Comment: To test the query return correct objects with correct permissions which mean the returned objects should not be deleted or the owner is suspended etc